# Update part of the date in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

i have table like this

```
ID Value
112 x
113 y
114 z
115 e
```

and i want to update ID cell with 'x' in the end so output updated value should be '112x'
how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

For that you need ID column of type VARCHAR data type. So you can update it by

```
UPDATE Table SET ID = CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(20)) + Value
```

Otherwise you can add new column with VARCHAR data type and update in that like below

```
UPDATE Table SET NewCol = CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(20)) + Value
```

Comment: value means whatever im putting right after the id number right?

Comment: Value is actually column name which you mentioned in your question. You can also put static value in place of column name.

Comment: no no, i dont want to do anything to value,
i just need to update ID with key like output update should be 112CE
i want to add some keys to end of ID values

Comment: My query will not change data for value column. It will update data of ID column with data of ID + value. You can put some static value if you want by this : SET ID = CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(20)) + 'CE'

Answer (score 1):

Have you try this :

```
 Update tablename set ID = CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(20)) + Value
```

Answer (score 0):

If ID column having the datatype INT, its not possible to update with Varchar datatype.

> UPDATE Table SET ID = CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(20)) + Value

Won't works.

My suggession is

Create new column with varchar datatype then apply

> Alter table Tab add Nwcol varchar(100)
>
> UPDATE Table SET NewCol = CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(20)) + Value

Then rename the col with old name

> sp_rename 'table.new_column','old_column','Column'

Its done.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the other answers suggest

```
UPDATE Table SET ID = CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(20)) + Value
FROM <table>
```

This is NOT a good answer unless ID is of the type char(x). Most likely the ID column is an integer, which will cause a conversion error.

If ID is already a varchar(x), no casting is necessary, all you have to do is:

```
UPDATE Table SET ID = ID + Value
FROM <table>
```

Assuming ID is an integer. You could alter the column, so it can contain a varchar. This could cause problems if ID is autoincremential and everywhere else you are currently using this column. Using varchar as an ID column is not good practice eather. I don't recommand this.

But why would you combine an ID with a varchar value ? Those values should be in different columns. Instead you could do 1 of these 4 suggestions

-create a view containing the combination

```
CREATE VIEW v_test as 
SELECT ID, Value, CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)) + Value as CID FROM <table>
```

-create a computed column containing the combination

```
ALTER table <table> ADD cID as CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)) + Value
```

-create a computed column containing the combination with a possible index. Persisted computed columns allows index.

```
ALTER table <table> ADD cID as CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)) + Value PERSISTED
```

-display the value in a select (which is what I assume you need)

```
SELECT CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)) + Value as DisplayID
FROM table
```